# How to access specific div related to element which raised an event?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a website where users can ask questions and allow others to reply to them. The questions are contained in a `div` which then contains another `div` with a CSS property of `display: none`.

I have a button in the mother `div` which will then open the div containing the reply or comment form. My code is working fine,

Now, my only problem is that whenever I click on the comment button it opens all the other reply-section `div`, even in the questions where the user did not click.

How can I get the specific div where the user clicked the reply button and only open the reply form of that mother div only and not all the others?

Comment: You need to use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to find related elements. Sadly you haven't shown any of your actual HTML code, nor a sample of your JS so no one can actually show you how to do this

Comment: I have a template which is fed with information from the database using the php array.  I then include this in my html body to echo all the question from the database.  My question is spacifically how to get the specific mother div that the e

Comment: In that case the only answer anyone can give you was in my first comment - use DOM traversal.

Comment: If you want more specific help, at least add html structure to your question. Don't just describe it.

Comment: Am a little bit new to jquery.  If you could include a sample or explain a bit more that would be of great help to me

Comment: Am talking about the traversal methods or functions that you mentioned please.  Thanks

Comment: Post a cut down snippet that illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    //here the button element is pointed by -this-!!!
    //so "this" is the element contained in your div...
    $(this).parent("questionDiv") //<- will point to the div that contain the button
    //so, having the button (this), you can get the parent element that contain the question and in it the mother div
});
```

[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), also check [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Hope this clarify what I understood from your question :)

I'm going to assume some thing...

DOM: Your html code

```
<div class="mother">
    <div class="question">
        <button class="respBtn">Respond</button>
    </div>
    <div class="respond"> ..more elemnts.. </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".respBtn").click(function(){
          console.log("click");
          //here goes the code that shows the div
            let moderDiv = $(this).parents(".mother");
            console.log(moderDiv.html());
            moderDiv.find("div.respond").each(function(){
              $(this).show();
          });
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
   .respond{
       display : none ;
   }
```

This is an example... jquery takes care of knowing which button was pressed ans to point to the right part of the DOM.

Hope this clarify my idea :)

Comment: Ok thanks.  But my question divs have the same if all of them since they are echoed out from a loop.  So the template is repeated over and over again until the loop ends.  This means that all the mother divs and also question divs have the same id... Please help

Comment: The id should be by definition unique, you could change in the PHP script the echo loop changing the `id` with `class`. also if you can share the loop code so I can see the structure of the DOM...

Comment: $questions = get_questions();

Comment: questions = get_questions();  while($questions){//here I echo my template};  // this loop is from a function get_questions() that fetches the questions from a database.  I then echo my data using the array for example for the question itself : <p><?php echo $questions['question ']; ?></p>       // but this code does not have a problem as it echoes out all the data I need.  The problems comes in when opening the specific div containing the reply box.  It opens all the reply box div in all the questions

Comment: So how can I make the id unique and how can I then open that specific reply  box div after the user clicks on the reply button on one of the mother divs

Comment: Hey thanks you very much.  Your code worked a miracle for me.  How can I vote for you and your answer???  Because you completely solved my problem in more than three days. Am new here and I think there is a way I can vote for you.  Thanks

Comment: [To accept an answer:](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.